# nmap script running error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i installed python-nmap-0.1.4.tar.gz in pyhton27 in window. When i ran this http://codepad.org/vTu1Uw7I script, i got a few error. What those error mean?. Are those error happened because i used python-nmap-0.1.4.tar.gz in windows?.

**Here is the error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/nmap/run-nmap.py", line 3, in <module>
        nm = nmap.PortScanner()      # instantiate nmap.PortScanner object
```

---

```
File "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/nmap\nmap.py", line 118, in __init__
p = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', '-V'], bufsize=10000, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

**Here is the subprocess.py script**

http://codepad.org/SpbV8muR

Comment: if installing nmap doesn't fix `python-nmap`; you could try [`scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `python-nmap` is meant to be run on Linux… but you can still try to make it work on Windows. The problem is that it is trying to call `nmap` but the binary is not found in [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

Add the directory with `nmap` executable to you `PATH` variable. Here is a [HOWTO](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: `nmap` works on Windows since 2000. You could get similar error on Linux if `nmap` is not installed. Though python-nmap itself might be *nix only.

Comment: Actually, i'm working on a script when it can find information about hosts on a network. So i started with nmap..

Comment: i add the directory to path variable. Variable value : C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nmap . But still got the same error

Comment: @topfer19 errr… You have to add the direcory with **`nmap` executable**. For example, `C:\Program Files\nmap\`. Chapter on Windows nmap installation has a section on updating `PATH` at the end. Here is the link: http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html

Comment: I installed nmap from [here](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/), with 'setup.py install'. Where would the exe be (directory-ways)?

Comment: Do I have to download the exe separately?